# JBoss 7.1: Persistent EjbTimer - how to?

Tags: jboss7.x

does anybody know how to make EJBTimers persistent not in filesystem, but in selected database table?
Like, for instance, in JBoss 4.x.x with the help of ejb-deployer.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server>
...
  <mbean code="org.jboss.ejb.txtimer.EJBTimerServiceImpl"
    name="jboss.ejb:service=EJBTimerService">
    <attribute name="RetryPolicy">jboss.ejb:service=EJBTimerService,retryPolicy=fixedDelay</attribute>
    <attribute name="PersistencePolicy">jboss.ejb:service=EJBTimerService,persistencePolicy=database</attribute>
    <attribute name="TimerIdGeneratorClassName">org.jboss.ejb.txtimer.BigIntegerTimerIdGenerator</attribute>
    <attribute name="TimedObjectInvokerClassName">org.jboss.ejb.txtimer.TimedObjectInvokerImpl</attribute>
    <depends optional-attribute-name="TransactionManagerFactory" proxy-type="org.jboss.tm.TransactionManagerFactory">
      jboss:service=TransactionManager
    </depends>
  </mbean>

  <!-- A retry policy that uses a fixed interval in milli seconds -->
  <mbean code="org.jboss.ejb.txtimer.FixedDelayRetryPolicy" name="jboss.ejb:service=EJBTimerService,retryPolicy=fixedDelay">
    <attribute name="Delay">100</attribute>
  </mbean>

  <mbean code="org.jboss.ejb.txtimer.DatabasePersistencePolicy" name="jboss.ejb:service=EJBTimerService,persistencePolicy=database">
    <!-- DataSourceBinding ObjectName -->
    <depends optional-attribute-name="DataSource">jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=DefaultDS</depends>
    <!-- The plugin that handles database persistence -->
    <attribute name="DatabasePersistencePlugin">org.jboss.ejb.txtimer.GeneralPurposeDatabasePersistencePlugin</attribute>
    <!-- The timers table name -->
    <attribute name="TimersTable">TIMERS</attribute>
  </mbean>
</server>
```

I've found nothing how to replace this one:

```
<timer-service thread-pool-name="default">
  <data-store path="timer-service-data" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
</timer-service>
```

to force timers to be persisted in DB.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, persistent EJBTimers are stored to the filesystem only. A corresponding [issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-1534) already exists. Unfortunately, it is targeted for the EAP system only... Take a look at the [Cron Module of Seam 3](http://seamframework.org/Seam3/CronModule). This module works with Quartz which provides JDBC stored timers.